# (Python) Dictionary not recognizing keys

Tags: python, dictionary

This is probably a stupid one.
So, I have this dictionary, which includes a few keys.
When I print the keys (as a list),

```
keys = list(dict.keys())
print(keys)
```

I get the output:

```
[b'batch_label', b'labels', b'data', b'filenames']
```

So far so good. But, when I try to access one of them,

```
return dict['labels']
```

I get a key error ('labels'). Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your keys are not strings, but `bytes` objects. Thus, you should access them as bytes

```
x[b'label']
```

Notice that

```
>>> b'label' is'label'
False
>>> b'label' == 'label'
False
```

If you don't want to access this way, you can decode them to strings by specifying an encoding type. For example,

```
new_dict = {k.decode('utf-8'): v for k,v in x.items()}
```

Now you can do

```
new_dict['label']
```